# insert space into parsed item

Tags: php, parsing

I have a working parsing script. I outsource most of the work, but there is just one small item remaining. The page I am parsing renders a postal code with no space (which is incorrect). So, i need to insert space after the 3rd character. I know the string to do that, I just don't know how to place it into this code portion:

```
if(preg_match('/postal: (.*),/', $tempscript, $matches))
$temppostcode = $matches[1];
$postcode=str_replace('"','',substr($temppostcode,0,strpos($temppostcode,'", ')));
```

The string I was trying to place into the above portion:

```
$postcode = str_replace(' ','',$postcode);
$postcode = wordwrap($postcode, strlen($postcode)-3,' ', true);
```

I just don't know where to place this in the first portion to make it work, or what alternatives I have.

Comment: I can't see the problem just put your code after that code

Comment: if your passing html with regular repression you outsourced it to a fool

Comment: @popnoodles I tried that - to no effect

Comment: @Dagon maybe if you saw what was being parsed, your comment might have some validity. Most of it can be parsed as html, but there are some parts of the page that can't.

Comment: @popnoodles I stand corrected! I tried it, but I first removed the spaces before and after the equal signs (???) and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: the spaces make no difference. perhaps it didn't upload until you made that last change.